# Why doesn't the active cell change on open with this code in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi Google Sheets and Apps Script Programmers - 
I have read every thread that pertains to setting the focus to a certain cell on the open event of a Google Sheet, and I can't get the focus off of A1. I need the active cell to be B3, not A1. For instance, in an onOpen function, I have tried these various statements and none work:

```
ss.sheet("MySubShop").setActiveCell(range("B3"));
MySubShop.setActiveCell(range("B3"));
mySubShop.getRange("B3").activate();
mySubShop.getRange("B3").setActiveCell();
firstcell.activate(); //where firstcell is var firstcell = mySubShop.getRangeByName("cashiername");
```

Here are some of the variables at the top:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var mySubShop  = ss.getSheetByName("MySubShop"); //my main order form
```

I'm familiar with VBA but new to GAS. Any help would be so greatly appreciated. THanks much.

HERE IS THE COMPLETE CODE FOR THE APP:

```
//MAKE VARIABLES
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("B3");
var values = range.getValues();      

var mySubShop  = ss.getSheetByName("MySubShop"); //my main order form
var orders = ss.getSheetByName("Orders"); //Order data
var breads = ss.getSheetByName("Breads");
var meats = ss.getSheetByName("Meats");
var cheeses = ss.getSheetByName("Cheeses");
var condiments = ss.getSheetByName("Condiments");
var sides = ss.getSheetByName("Sides");
var beverages = ss.getSheetByName("Beverages");

//YOU CAN GET VALUES OF CELLS AND SET VARS = TO THEM
var lastrow = orders.getLastRow();
var thecolumn = 1;

//WHEN THE SHEET OPENS
function onOpen() {

  if (lastrow==1) {

    var ordernum = 1;

    mySubShop.getRange("B5").setValue(ordernum);     
  } 
  else if (lastrow > 1) {

    ordernum = orders.getRange(lastrow, thecolumn).getValue()+1;
    mySubShop.getRange("B5").setValue(ordernum);
  }

  return ordernum;

  mySubShop.getRange("B3").activate();
}


function submitData() {
  var newordernum = onOpen(); 

  //Get the order info
  var ordersvalues = [[mySubShop.getRange("B5").getValue(), 
                       mySubShop.getRange("B4").getValue(), 
                       mySubShop.getRange("B3").getValue(),
                       mySubShop.getRange("B2").getValue()]];

  orders.getRange(orders.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(ordersvalues);

  //increase the order number ready for the next order
  mySubShop.getRange("B5").setValue(newordernum+1);
  //call the clearMe function
  clearMe();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole script for replicating your issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: `mySubShop.getRange("B3").activate();` should work. if it doesn't, check view>stackdriver error

Comment: Thanks Tanaike and TheMaster for responding. TheMaster - Yes, the code you provided should do it. I must be missing something though because it still just keeps the focus on A1 when the workbook opens. Tanaike - Here is all of my code. I am trying to make a fun little app for a sub sandwich shop, basically using the workbook kind of like a database. There will be a number of sheets: MySubShop, Orders, Meats, Cheeses, Bread, etc.